# Connecting Kinect to Processing through OpenNI & SimpleOpenNI on a Mac

Tags: processing, kinect, openni, simple-openni

I'm trying to connect Kinect to Processing on a Mac (running OSX Yosemite 10.10). Perhaps someone can help?

Thus far, I've followed all the directions on this page, with no errors (a very helpful page by the way): 
http://blog.nelga.com/setup-microsoft-kinect-on-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/

Once completed, I was able to use Kinect via Terminal, NiTE, & SensorKinect without a problem. However, when I try to utilize the SimpleOpenNI library via Processing, it tells me I need to install OpenNI first. Given that OpenNI is already installed, in the steps above, I'm not sure what's wrong. I've tried restarting and whatnot.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Which version of Processing and SimpleOpenNI are you using ? (I've just tested on OSX 10.10.5 with Processing 2.2.1 and SimpleOpenNI Version 1.96 and it seems to work).

Answer (score 1):

**Processing** uses libraries under `~/Documents/Processing/Library/`. You have to follow the instruction here: https://simple-openni.googlecode.com and also install OpenNI-NITE as driver.

There is an open source example you can follow and all required libraries are given with links: https://github.com/ningt/slide2d